# View/show has unknown column in Many2Many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I thought I could beat this to death by systematically moving through options.
It Won.

index.html.erb and form.html.erb work as things are now.

I have a many to many relationship between Bids and Contacts, with bids_contacts in between with bid_id and customer_contact_id in that table.

Here's the contacts then bids models:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :bid_customer_contacts, :class_name => 'Bid',
  :association_foreign_key => 'bid_id'

has_and_belongs_to_many :customer_contacts, :class_name => 'Contact', :foreign_key => 'customer_contact_id'
```

Nothing special in bids_controller.rb

The show.html.erb file errors with:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'bids_contacts.contact_id' in 'on clause':   
SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` INNER JOIN `bids_contacts'  
    ON  `contacts`.`id` = `bids_contacts`.`contact_id'  
 WHERE  'bids_contacts`.`customer_contact_id` = 15
```

The code is:

```
<b>Customer Contacts:</b>
<% if !@bid.customer_contacts.empty? %>   <<===============
  <ul>
    <% @bid.contacts.each do |bc| %>
        <li><%= link_to(bc.name, bc) %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% else %>
    No Customer Contacts<br/>
<% end %>
```

I've tried **contact_id** in the M2M table rather than **customer_contact_id**, but I just get different errors.

Let me know if I need to share something else to get this mystery solved.
Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get while using `contact_id` in join table?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you're calling

```
@bid.customer_contacts
```

and then later

```
@bid.contacts
```

You probably want

```
@bid.customer_contacts
```

both times, since you defined the method this way with

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :customer_contacts ...
```

I assume you have customer_contact_id as a field in your database, but when you call .contacts your view looks for the contact_id field which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks anotherthink.  Right before I went home that day I got it.  Sometimes they're so simple.